# disappearing headers in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

[image: Here's the table view itself.]

I managed a way to animate my cells. I created a global variable named rowHeight in type of CGFloat and implicitly assigned it as 40. I wrote this code down:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {


        return rowHeight
    }
```

In the touch event:

```
@IBAction func lessonCollapser(sender: AnyObject) {

        if rowHeight == 40 {

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {self.rowHeight = 0})

        self.tableView.endUpdates()

        } else if rowHeight == 0 {

            self.tableView.beginUpdates()

            UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {self.rowHeight = 40})

            self.tableView.endUpdates()

        }

    }
```

So far so good. Even though it is being animated, there are a few problems.

**First:** My custom headers disappear.

**Second:** I get an error: "no index path for table cell being reused". I think because there are no index paths, the headers are disappeared. That is expected. What is not expected is that, why my tables' index paths disappeared when I used the animation? I think that is because of the `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`. Can someone advice me something to do?

The code for my header view:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {



        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as! lessonHeaderTableViewCell

        switch (section) {

        default:
            headerCell.lessonHeader.setTitle("TEST HEADER", forState: .Normal)

        }


        return headerCell
    }
```

What happens on the code above is this: I created a prototype cell with "headerCell" identifier. I threw a button inside it. I created a swift file named "lessonHeaderTableViewCell. I assigned it as class of the prototype cell so it could control it. Lastly, I created an outlet named "lessonHeader" for the button, inside the swift file that I created.

[image: This is how it looks like after collapse.]